# Grails CXF Pluggin

Tags: java, rest, grails, cxf, cxfrs

I am new to CXF and hence kindly spare me if my question is too dumb.

I intend to develop a REST service using Grails which accepts a custom JAVA Object. Hence I intend to use [grails-cxf](https://github.com/Grails-Plugin-Consortium/grails-cxf) plugin.

In my controller, I need a method (POST) which accepts a Java Object and return a Java Object

```
def UserDetails getUserDetails(User user)
{
   // Logic

   return new UserDetails();
}
```

I don't see any good example in the Plugin's documentation. I am not very particular about using this plugin. If you can suggest any way of achieving it with grails, its fine with me.

Please Help. Can we use grails-cxf pluggin to develop REST APIs ?

Comment: First of all `def UserDetails getUserDetails(User user)` should be `UserDetails getUserDetails(User user)` or `def getUserDetails(User user)`

Comment: I agree, but the above method was just a sample to explain what I am trying achieve. Basically a Rest Method to accept Java Objects as arguements

Answer (score 0):

You have to define in the `config.groovy` where the cxf Plugin is looking for the Service.

Fore Example:

```
cxf {
  servlet {
    loadOnStartup = 10
  }
  servlets = [
        CxfServlet: '/services/*'
  ]
  endpoint {
    soap12Binding = false
   }
}
```

So the Plugin looks in the Service folder for some WebServices, but you need to define a Service as a WebService.
For your example the Service maybe looks like this :

```
class UserDetailsService {
  static expose = EndpointType.JAX_RS

  @WebResult(name = 'getUserDetails')
  @WebMethod
  UserDetails getUserDetails(@WebParam(name = 'user')User user)
  {
      // Logic

      return new UserDetails();
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if it works with the User Object, I never did that with an Java Object.
If it doesn't work you could use the UserId and get the User inside the method.

HTH

Comment: So Kind of you to answer. Let me try and update you. Can I invoke  getUserDetails REST API through any REST client ?

Comment: can you please help and tell me what would be the REST url for the above getUserDetails api ?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't need a cxf pluggin to achieve Rest Service accepting Java Objects as arguements.

**Command Object** served my purpose